# Oracle Lag- determine if previous row columns are the same as current row

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, analytical

Is it possible using analytical functions in oracle (lag for instance) to check the previous row, and based on 2 columns, determine if these values are exactly the same as the current row. If they are, then output the letter 'Y', else 'N'.

Something like:

```
IF prev.col1 = curr.col1 and prev.col2 = curr.col2 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
```

I want to use this Y or N to filter out these records in a Crystal Report that I am writing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but as analytics are processed fairly late, you need write the query with the analytic as a subquery:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = prev_col1 AND col2 = prev_col2 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as yesno
  FROM (
SELECT col1, col2, 
       LAG( col1, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY col1, col2 ) AS prev_col1
       LAG( col2, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY col1, col2 ) AS prev_col2
  FROM mytable
)
```

You'll need to adjust the `ORDER BY` clause depending on how you're defining the "previous" row. You may also want to add a `PARTITION BY` clause if you don't want to treat the whole table as a single group of rows.